# Find out which keyguard-type a user is using

Tags: android, lockscreen, keyguard, keyguardlock

`DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()` only works if the user is *not* using the "Slide"/"None"-lockscreen (on some devices). Thus, I'd like to find out which lockscreen-type (None/Slide/PIN/Pattern/Face-Unlock) the user is currently using. Is this possible (across manufacturers)?

Thanks!